# C++ - Object destructed when out of scope and in vector

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

Why is the destructor of an object called when it goes out of scope and when it is in a vector ?
For example :

```
std::vector<Foo> vec;
for (i=10; i<10; i++)
{
   Foo object(i);
   vec.push_back(object);
}
```

Is the destructor of object called because it goes each time out of scope? Can I make it work without pointers or shared_pointers?

Comment: Yes; use `emplace_back` and build `Foo` in place.

Comment: What ends up in a vector is a copy of `object`, not `object` itself. `object` is destroyed when it goes out of scope; its copy lives on inside the vector. It's not clear from your question why you consider this to be an issue. What actual problem, if any, are you trying to solve?

Comment: I was confused and thought that the vector took a pointer of the object since the function push_back takes the object by reference. Thanks.

Comment: A reference is not a pointer (unless we're talking about how compilers implement references, but we're not).  A reference is basically a different name for the referenced entity, and is often used when passing objects.  Since your vector stores `Foo`, and not `Foo&`, it'll use that reference to copy construct its own `object`, at which point refer to what @Igor said above.

Comment: Thanks. Although I know that a reference is not a pointer and that one can't make arrays or references.

Comment: Am I the only one to notice that the loop is never going to run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`object` will die out of this scope, this is correct. No, `vector` doesn't and couldn't affect its lifetime. `push_back` actually copies `object` into the `vector`. To avoid this, you can use C++11's `emplace_back` which allows to construct `Foo` in-place:

```
vec.emplace_back(i);
```

[This test program](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/89683e329607f210) confirms no copy, move or extra destruction is performed.

```
Constructing A
End of vec's scope
Destructing A
```

Comment: That still creates a temporary `Foo`, then copies it into the vector, then destroys it right away. The net effect is exactly the same as the original code (except that it uses a default constructor of `Foo`, whereas the original uses the constructor taking an `int`). You likely meant `vec.emplace_back(i);` or `vec.emplace_back();` - this does construct one and only instance of `Foo` in-place (using a one-parameter or default constructor, correspondingly).

Comment: Correct, I got confused. I realized that later on when experimenting on Coliru. push_back and emplace_back aren't much different in this case : http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b2894b7f4b2a8367

Comment: Again - in order to see the difference, make it `vec.emplace_back()`

Comment: I think you answer works the best for me, because the destructor of my object is costly so it's better to create just one object.

Comment: oh, I missed the point and didn't know how emplace_back was meant to be used. i will edit back my answer accordingly to this. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

- push_back pushes a **copy** of the object to the vector
- object will actually be destroyed but a copy will persist in the vector
- If you want to push the exact content of the object in the vector and have the code work then use the **move contructor**

Comment: So if I use a move constructor the object does not destruct?

Comment: it will be destroyed but its content will be transferred into the vector, no copy will be done. that is more efficient

Comment: Ok, the problem is that in my object destructor, it destoys elements in another objects, so I don't want it to destroy these elements.

Comment: I didn't need to use a destructor in such cases for a while now. What kind of elements are those? Dynamic allocation? Then try dropping it and use `shared_ptr`.

Comment: I did not see all your code. try the move and tell me. It preserves the content of the object. If not, you need to send me some more code or MP me.

Comment: In my code, I have entities that store components as shared_pointers. They are also stored as a copy of the shared_pointers in a system. A system is in charge to update the components of each entity, so it needs an vector of all of the corresponding types of components (there are multiple of them).

Comment: Let's say you have an entity :

Comment: should be fine because if you don't call the destructor of the class, the members of the class won't have their destructors called

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
std::vector<Foo> vec;
for (i=10; i<10; i++)
{
   vec.emplace_back(i);
}
```

Comment: you should remove `foo object(i);`

Comment: That should be removed